# Data base Oracle

Tags: ado.net, odp.net

Can you explain for me 
1)what are Ado.net and Odp.net
2)what is diffrent between Adp.net and Odp.net 
?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: Ado.net is Microsoft's OOP abstraction of doing database related work, providing strongly typed interfaces so you simply can exchange the backend database by only programming against the interfaces.

Odp.net (ODP = Oracle Data Provider) is an implementation of the ado.net interfaces for the oracle database system.